# How can I tell if server-side apply is enabled in my Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-apiserver

The [page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/server-side-apply/) on server-side apply in the Kubernetes docs suggests that it can be enabled or disabled (e.g., the docs say, "If you have Server Side Apply enabled ...").

I have a GKE cluster and I would like to check if server-side apply is enabled. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating any object like **namespace** or so and try checking the YAML output using the command you will get an idea if SSA is enabled or not.

**Command** :

`kubectl create ns test-ssa`

Get the created namespace

```
kubectl get ns test-ssa -o yaml
```

If there is **managedFields** existing in output SSA is working.

**Server-side-apply** i think introduced around **K8s** version **1.14** and now it's in **GA** with k8s version **1.22**. Wiht GKE i have noticed it's already been part of it alpha or beta.

If you are using the **HELM** on your **GKE** you might have noticed the **Service Side Apply**.